# jq: create new json basing on existing json with usage if else

Tags: json, jq

now I have following problem.

there is such input json

```
{
“inn” : “qwerty”,
“cuid” : “1234”,
“type” : "legal",
“reqId” : “asdfg”
}
```

It should be transformed into

```
{
“inn” : “qwerty”,
“reqId” : “asdfg”
}
```

or into

```
{
“cuid” : “1234”,
“reqId” : “asdfg”
}
```

it depends on a value of "type" field. How can I do that with JQ?

My attempts were failed, it all was about trying such way

.inn as $inn | .cuid as  $cuid | {if .type == "person" then $inn else $cuid end}

but it gave such result

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD, expecting ':' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
> .inn as $inn | .cuid as  $cuid | {if .type == "person" then $inn else $cuid end}
> jq: 1 compile error
> exit status 3

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid JSON object.

Comment: I've edited, the problem is actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the following filter where:

- `.type == "person"` --> We use keys: `inn` and `reqId`
- `.type != "person"` --> We use keys: `cuid` and `reqId`

We can use:

```
if .type == "person" then { inn } else { cuid } end + { reqId }
```

The differences I've made:

- Added the last part: `+ { reqId }`. Here we add the `reqId` to the object created by the `if` statement.
- I've removed the `.inn as $inn` part this we can just use the key for this.

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SDAOLxPehi)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem easily with one `if then else end` expression:

```
jq 'if .type == "person"
    then {inn, reqId}
    else {cuid, reqId}
    end' <<< '{ "inn" : "qwerty", "cuid" : "1234", "type" : "legal", "reqId" : "asdfg" }'

# result
# {
#   "cuid": "1234",
#   "reqId": "asdfg"
# }

jq 'if .type == "person"
    then {inn, reqId}
    else {cuid, reqId}
    end' <<< '{ "inn" : "qwerty", "cuid" : "1234", "type" : "person", "reqId" : "asdfg" }'

# result
# {
#   "inn": "qwerty",
#   "reqId": "asdfg"
# }
```